# Redirect if cookie is null

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I'm now learning about cookies and and got my cookie code form this [page on w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Here on StackOverflow I looked up about redirecting and I've attempted to redirect to here is the cookie has not been set. This will redirect to a page on my server to accept cookie policy and customize the admin panel theme.

```
<!-- Javascript BEFORE page loads Starts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var user=getCookie("username");
            if (user != "") {
                alert("Cookie Set: " + user);
            } else {
               //user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
               if (user != "" && user != null) {
                   window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
               }
            }
        }
    </script>
<!-- Javascript BEFORE page loads Starts -->

</head>
<!-- Header Ends -->

<!-- Body Starts -->
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

Comment: Here, read this, it might help you find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page

Comment: @WildChild He's doing what the answer there says.

Comment: You cannot implement access control on the client.  You need server-side code.

Comment: Access control means what please @SLaks

Comment: Your script will never redirect. You should change/remove the condition before window.location.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you checking for `user!="" && user!= null` in the `else` block? the `user` variable is guaranteed to be empty when code enters in this block. This is why `window.location.replace` isn't executing and the reason why its not redirecting.

```
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

   function checkCookie() {
   var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Cookie Set: " + user);
    } else {
       //user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
           setCookie("username", "value", 1);
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work either, and as stated I am learning and this is with w3schools did, I cannot say why sorry.

Comment: Bingo and wow that is weird, when you nav back it's like you didn't go on the original page. Is this avoidable alike a link click?

Comment: @TimMarshall You have to implement the setCookie() method as shown here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). When the user goes back to the site, the code should handle the case if the cookie is present.

Comment: I know, I linked to that in my question. What I am now asking is that upon going to my page it takes me to here however navigating back it was like I never went to my page in the first place. [Click here to try](admin.rafflebananza.com/newadmin.html)

Comment: @TimMarshall You have to set the `username` cookie. Please see my updated code. When you navigate back, the if block will run and it won't redirect here.

Comment: @TimMarshall window.location.replace replaces the current history item so you can't go back to it. use window.location.href instead

Comment: @MarcoMagrini I tried ` window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";` which also seemed to replace. which you can test above in the comments